# Google Map not displaying in Chrome / Firefox browser

Tags: browser, geolocation

I am trying to test Geolocation in HTML 5 in my browser. But for some reason, it is not displaying the lat and long for my place. Nor even the error message

Why is the lat and long not displaying. please assist. I tried on Chrome and FF. same result. Does it not display result all time or takes time

```
window.onload = checkLocation;
function checkLocation() {
//we put the if condition that will check if the browser supports geplocationn feature or not
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    //if yes, then call the getCurremtPosition method and pass in a handler function ()

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, showError);

    // And we’re calling the geolocation object’s getCurrentPosition method with one argument, the success callback.
}else {

    alert(' Hey No locator for your browser');
}
}

function showLocation(position) {


//position parameter is passed so as to get getCurrentPosition’s handler is passed a position, which contains the latitude and longitude of your location

// get the lat and lon of location from the cords object
var lat = position.coords.lat;
var lon = position.coords.lon;

var content = document.getElementById('myLocation');

content.innerHTML = ' Your latitude position is: ' + lat + ' and your Longtitude position is:  ' + lon + '</br>';

}

function showError(error) {
var errorList = {
//We create an object with three properties named zero to three. 
//These properties are strings with an error message we want to associate with each code

    0: 'Unknown error',
    1: 'Permission denied by user',
    2: 'Position not available',
    3: 'Request timed out'
};

var errorMsg = errorList[error.code];// use error code property to access the error list []

if(error.code == 0 || error.code == 2) {
    errorMsg = errorMsg + " " + error.message; // use erroo message property ro access the value in error list
}
var content = document.getElementById('myLocation');

content.innerHTML = erroMsg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW i have found the issue. While calling the map api script, make sure the url starts with // and not http. Let google decide how it wants to serve the api file.